# beeline - hive udf doesn't show logs when executed with aggregate function

Tags: hadoop, logging, hive, log4j

I have a hive UDF and I am trying to redirect logs from my UDF to  `hive-server2.log`. I am using `beeline` for executing queries. And so I have modified following file.

**/etc/hive/conf.dist/beeline-log4j2.properties**

```
status = INFO
name = BeelineLog4j2
packages = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.log

# list of properties
property.hive.log.level = INFO
property.hive.root.logger = console

# list of all appenders
appenders = console

# console appender
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_ERR
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} [%t]: %p %c{2}: %m%n

# list of all loggers
loggers = HiveConnection

# HiveConnection logs useful info for dynamic service discovery
logger.HiveConnection.name = org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection
logger.HiveConnection.level = INFO

# root logger
rootLogger.level = ${sys:hive.log.level}
rootLogger.appenderRefs = root
rootLogger.appenderRef.root.ref = ${sys:hive.root.logger}

# loggr for UDF 
log4j.logger.com.abc=DEBUG,console
```

I tried, redirecting logs to seperate file. however it's not working.

```
log4j.logger.com.abc=DEBUG, console, rollingFile
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=/tmp/bmo.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.rollingFile.append=true
```

I am facing two issues.

1. doesn't matter what level I set for my logger I only gets info logs. I not able to see debug logs.
2. If I use some aggregate function (i.e. min, max) with my UDF i am not able to see any logs. Where can I find logs? logs appears only if I use just udf on column.